# Tell Markdown to ignore everything in <code> block?

Tags: ruby, markdown, bluecloth

Markdown already ignores everything within a `<div>` element, and various other block-level elements.  However, I need to tell Markdown to ignore everything within `<code>` blocks as well.  Is there a way to tell Markdown to do this?

As an FYI, I am using [BlueCloth](https://github.com/ged/bluecloth).

Answer (score 0):

The Markdown [spec](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode) does not specify how `<code>` blocks should be processed. What exact type of markup are you trying to get the Markdown processors to ignore?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Markdown Syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) page.

I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve.

You have something like the following right?

```
#Heading

<code>
    $my = 'php code here';
</code>

Other text
```

Do you want your output to be like the one below?

```
<h1>Heading</h1>

<code>
    $my = 'php code here';
</code>

<p>Other text</p>
```

For code in markdown you have to indent the code by four spaces so what you should do is the following in your markdown source file.

```
#Heading

    $my = 'php code here';

Other text
```

The code is indented four spaces and markdown will surround it with  and  tags automatically.